# How to send luggage by train from NJP to Palakkad in India?

Tags: luggage, india, bookings, indian-railways

I would like to know the procedures to book luggage from NJP (New Jalpaiguri Junction Station) to Palakkad. I am not traveling with my luggage.

Can someone tell me the complete procedure of booking luggage?

Comment: Why does it have to go from the station? Are you wanting to send luggage by train only? Not mail? Is someone picking it up at the other end? Can you plelase elaborate on your requirements. Putting on hold for now

Answer (score 1):

The Indian Railway Parcel Website helps you to book your luggage online, if you are not travelling onboard

There are two ways you can do this :

*Parcel booking* & *Luggage booking*

**Parcel booking :**

- Parcel booking can be done by going to your nearest station and filling a parcel form and you leave your goods there and you can expect it to reach your destination within 5 to 7 days. Please carry some identity proof for parcel filling.
- To receive your goods you/someone else have to go to the destination railways station and present your receipt (which can be delivered at the destination by post).
- You wont be traveling on the same train and it costs a bit extra as compared to luggage booking.
- Another important thing to note is parcel bookings can only be done during office hours on working days.
- Just go to the [Parcel Booking](http://www.parcel.indianrail.gov.in/) and you can do the needful as per the instructions provided.

**Note:** The charges for railway parcel is very low but they charge more for stuffs like bike. It's better to send bulkier items as the handling of your item is very poorly done.

**Other Means**

**India Post Logistics Post Service:** They will deliver it to doorstep and it takes 3-4 days. There are flat charges for items up to 50 kg.

**Buses :** You can also find some buses going from A to B and ask them to carry and they will carry and charge some money.

**Professional Courier companies :** Costly but reliable and timely.